# XCode4 can not Watch value of variables

Tags: xcode4

It's a bit annoying that when I hit a break point in XCode 4, values of Watch Expressions are always grayed out. I have to create dummy variables pointing to the thing I want to watch in order to get around it.

The log says the following errors when I run the app:

warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit (file not found).
warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c++
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As for myself, I debug variables using two handy GDB console commands. You can enter them when in debug mode in debug console after GDB mark. I use "p" command for printing basic C type variables:

```
p [[[self pointerToMyClass] anotherPointerToOtherClass] someIntValue]
```

And I use "po" command for printing content of arrays, for checking objects:

```
po [[[self pointerToMyClass] anotherPointerToOtherClass] someNSArray]
po [[[self pointerToMyClass] anotherPointerToOtherClass] myUIImageView]
```